# How to disable UIButton that created programmatically in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subview, isenabled

I created unbutton programmatically in a function and now i want to disable it from another function in ViewController in iOS Objective C.

```
-(void)makeButton{
self.markerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIImage *markerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:markerImageName];
    self.markerButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.mView.bounds.size.width/2)-(markerImage.size.width/2), (self.mView.bounds.size.height/2)-(markerImage.size.height), markerImage.size.width, markerImage.size.height);
    self.markerButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [self.markerButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.markerButton.btnData = self.markerButton;
    [self.markerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:markerImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.markerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(markerButtonClicked:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.mView addSubview:self.markerButton]; 

-(void)anotherFunction{
     self.markerButton.enable = NO;
}
```

Comment: `self.markerButton.userInteractionEnabled=NO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply change `self.markerButton.enable = NO;` to `self.markerButton.userInteractionEnabled=NO;`

Answer (score 1):

To disable user interaction on a UIButton, you need to stop the User Interaction by method `userInteractionEnabled`

So your code should be

```
-(void)anotherFunction {
     self.markerButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```